# No reaction on click at all

Tags: java, android

This is example from Android for beginners book. I think that problem is with mNoteAdapter but I can't find where it exactly is. I tried to use adapter from other source and it was working(I mean click) so I could see at least log in logcat. How does mNoteAdapter  affect on possibility of seeing users click by app? How can I find where problem is?

```
        mNoteAdapter = new NoteAdapter();
        ListView listNote = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listNote.setAdapter(mNoteAdapter);

        listNote.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int 
        whichItem, long id) {
                Log.e("CLICK", "CliCK");       
             }
        });
    }
```

Here is a piece of NoteAdapter class

```
public class NoteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        List<Note> noteList = new ArrayList<Note>();
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
        }
        @Override
        public Note getItem(int whichItem) {
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int whichItem) {
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int whichItem, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, viewGroup, false);
            }
            TextView txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
             ImageView ivImportant = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageViewImportant);

            Note tempNote = noteList.get(whichItem);
            if (!tempNote.isImportant()) {
                ivImportant.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            txtTitle.setText(tempNote.getTitle());
            return view;
        }

        public void addNote(Note n) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This row was added to the top of .xml file

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to display items as list on Android.. 
   --> ListView, RecyclerView etc.

Lists need a source right? Let's assume that your source is an array of 1000 elements. Your ListView has to have as many columns to display all of them right?

- Adapter is responsible for taking the array, and assigning each element to every list placeholders

Comment: My adapter is doing exactly what you said. But how does adapter affect on click properties? Why app don't see that user is clicking on it?

Comment: You are implementing it wrong. Please take the Udacity Android courses, which are the best around for learning Android

Comment: Yes, I know that something is wrong, that's why I posted this question here

Comment: From your question it is clear that you havent got the basics. Don't worry you'll learn it.. But if I code for you , you'll know something has been changed, and not exactly what happened